# Using sort with the mat-table Not sorting or giving option to sort

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I a tried to implement the following [example](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#using-sort-with-the-mat-table) on my own table, I was unsuccessful, I followed multiple recommendation on Stack overflow but I also been unsuccessful.

Then I decided to implement exactly the example on fresh new app.

I am using angular 8

The type script I use:

```
import {LiveAnnouncer} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort, Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Table with sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
        export class TableSortingExample implements AfterViewInit {
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
    
      constructor(protected _jsonService: JsonFormsAngularService
        , private _globalService: GlobalService, private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer) {
        //
        super(_jsonService);
      }
    
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    
      /** Announce the change in sort state for assistive technology. */
      announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {
        // This example uses English messages. If your application supports
        // multiple language, you would internationalize these strings.
        // Furthermore, you can customize the message to add additional
        // details about the values being sorted.
        if (sortState.direction) {
          this._liveAnnouncer.announce(`Sorted ${sortState.direction}ending`);
        } else {
          this._liveAnnouncer.announce('Sorting cleared');
        }
  }
```

The Html I use:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)"
       class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by number">
      No.
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by name">
      Name
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by weight">
      Weight
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by symbol">
      Symbol
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

The result is basically no cursor to sort, no error or warnings in the web console.

[image]

Any idea why is not displaying the sorting mechanism? what can be the issue if is just exactly the example that Angular is giving? I tried every thing related on stack overflow, any one experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: when you inspect the DOM do you have in each "header" a div like: `<div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition ....>`? Is this div, when you hover the header show the arrow.

Comment: When I faced issues with the sort, I usually changed the assignment to be in a setter instead of ngAfterViewInit `@ViewChild(MatSort) set sort(value: MatSort) { this.dataSource.sort = value; }`

Comment: Eliseo When I inspect the DOM I don' have in each "header" a div has you have described, instead I am getting the following on each "th":
mat-header-cell="" mat-sort-header="" sortactiondescription="Sort by name" class="mat-header-cell cdk-header-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name ng-star-inserted